# Как в php записать значение массива  в переменную?

Tags: массивы, php

Есть многоуровневый массив:

```
$b=array(
  201=>(ab,ac,ad),
  202=>(bc,bd,bi),
  203=>(bq,ud,st)
);
```

Вопрос: как в переменную $s записать значение 202, а в $q - значение bi?  Уже перерыл весь Интернет и не могу найти решение. Надежда на вас.

**Обновление**

```
<? if(!isset($_REQUEST['send'])) {?>                    
   <form action="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>" id="start" method="post">                    
      <input type="tel" name="number" pattern="[1-9]{4}" required> <br>

      <input type="submit" name="send" value="Проверка">
   </form>
<? } else {?>
<? 
                            $userkod=$_REQUEST['number'];
    $open=array(
                            "7622"=>array("set1"=>"777", "set2"=>"res"),
                            "5026"=>array("set1"=>"888", "set2"=>"page")

);
                            $ul=$dostup[$userlog]);

$up=$open[$userkod]["set2"];

if($userkod==$ul) {?>
                                Сработало!
                                <? } else { ?>
                                    Ошибка кода!
<a href="../">Ввести еще раз</a>
<? echo $ul,up;}
                        }?>
```

Это мой код. Но он не работает. Не могу сравнить значение. Так как не могу достать значение с масива

Нашел решение - `in_array` - сначала неправильно его задействовал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Человеческий метод:

```
$s = array_keys($b);//получаем все ключи
$s = $s[1];//выбираем из них второй
$q = $b[$s][2];//выбираем из данного подмассива нужное по порядку значение.
```

Но скорее всего, вы делаете что-то не так. (с)
Чтобы узнать что и дать вам совет, надо понять изначальную задачу.

Comment: ага) затупил..

Comment: Зря удалили. У вас вполне годный был ответ, так как по изначальной задаче можно было и так тоже выполнить. У меня просто чуть менее стебный.

Comment: Если я в $s внесу $s=$b[$k] - $k - это вводимая переменная. Выдает в итоге array. А должно значение 202.

Comment: 202 - это ключ. Вы его так не получите.

Если $k = это уже 202, то не парьте мозг и делайте
$s = $k;

Comment: Про мой ответ $s=$b[202] - тут как бы уже никуда не годится - он же ему массив выдаст))

Comment: Обновил вопрос